# Guarantees of reordering of a vector

Tags: c++, vector, language-lawyer

Say I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> vec {10, 15, 20};
    auto itr = vec.begin();
    vec.erase(itr);
    for(const auto& element : vec)
    {
        std::cout << element << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This gives me `15 20` as expected. Now, cppreference says [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) about `erase()`:

> Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the
>   erase, including the end() iterator

Fair enough, but is that the only guarantee the standard gives about `vector::erase()`?

Is a vector allowed to reorder it's element after the erased iterator?

For example, are these conditions guaranteed to hold after the erase which would mean  all elements after the `erase()` iterator shifted 1 to the left:

```
vec[0] == 15
vec[1] == 20
```

Or are implementations allowed to move values around as they see fit, and thus, create scenarios where `vec[0] == 20` etc?

I would like a quote of the relevant part of the standard.

Comment: Under *Complexity* it says: *" the assignment operator of T is called the number of times equal to the number of elements in the vector after the erased elements"* - doesn't that mean it has to copy all following elements in order?

Comment: As you don't use the iterator after the erase(), I'm not sure what you are asking about.  Only the iterator is invalidated.

Comment: @NeilButterworth It's not about the iterator, it's about the state of the vector after the erase.

Comment: It's what you would expect it to be - it has two elements, 15 and 20.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Yes, and I asked if an implementation is allowed to make that 20 and 15 instead.

Comment: No, it isn't allowed to do so. Vectors are ordered/

Comment: well essentially it means that it will be reordered in the way that the items were removed if you remove 1 and 5 it'll start at 2 3 6 ...

Comment: @NeilButterworth And I ask for a standard quote on that.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to support your laziness. If you want to find out how a vector is specified, read the standard for yourself.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I've read it, and according to my conclusion they are allowed. Which is why I asked, that's not laziness. But fine, have it your way.

Comment: In case you don't know, cppreference is not the standard.

Comment: I also just read the standard, and for unordered associative containers there is the [explicit requirement](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements#unord.req-14) that the relative ordering of the elements is preserved. I couldn't find a similar statement for sequences though.

Comment: I'm fairly sure the standard doesn't guarantee your computer will not explode after calling `erase` either, but at some point you gotta read between the lines...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's start at the beginning:

> 23.2.3 Sequence containers
>
> A sequence container organizes a finite set of objects, all of the same type, into a strictly linear arrangement.
>   The library provides four basic kinds of sequence containers: vector,
>   forward_list, list, and deque.

Emphasis on "a strictly linear arrangement". This is unambiguous.

This definition is followed by a table called "sequence container requirements", which describes `erase()` thusly:

> ```
> a.erase(q) [ ... ]
> Effects:  Erases the element pointed to by q
> ```

Combined, this leaves no wiggle room for interpretation. The elements in a vector are always in "a strict linear arrangement", so when one of them is `erase()`d, there's only one possible outcome.

Comment: Well, some wiggle room - what does "strictly linear" mean, and is it specified elsewhere in the standard :-)  I would have rather said something like "ordered in the order of specific insertion operations", or something similar.

Answer (score 7):

Technically, no, the standard doesn't write out a promise that it won't re-order elements when you least expect.

Practically, *obviously* it's not going to do that. That would be ridiculous.

Legally, you can probably take the "Effects" clause:

> Erases the element pointed to by *q*

as having no *other* effects unless stated elsewhere (e.g. iterator invalidation, which follows from the erasure effect).

Comment: Sam's answer is better but I think there's still wiggle room for observing that the standard doesn't say outright that said _strictly linear arrangement_ isn't "re-linearised". But I am playing devil's advocate to a huge extent here, largely for fun.

Comment: "the standard doesn't write out a promise that it won't re-order elements when you least expect" - I think it bloody well should do this. I think we simply haven't tracked down where it does say this yet in unambiguous form. If it doesn't do so, then this is a bug in the standard. Such things do exist, and relying on what is "obvious" is not a good idea.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: I'm willing to agree that this could be considered an editorial defect, though I doubt we'll get any traction.

Comment: Not from here, certainly, but someone on the standard committee might like to think about what "strictly linear"" is supposed to mean, or even (shock, horror) define it.. Perhaps posting an SO question about it might raise its visibility? No, I'm not going to do so.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: I mean, I doubt the working group will care.

Answer (score 4):

The two statements I found that I think guarantee it would be:

**C++11 Standard**

> **23.2.1**
>   **11** Unless otherwise specified (either explicitly or by defining a function in terms of other functions), invoking a container member function or passing a container as an argument to a library function shall not invalidate iterators to, or change the values of, objects within that container.

If you can't "change the values of" then you can't arbitrarily re-order elements (like swapping the end value with the erased one).

> **23.2.3**
>   **12** The iterator returned from a.erase(q) points to the element immediately following q prior to the element being erased. If no such element exists, a.end() is returned.

This implies that the conceptual erasure of an element is implemented by closing the physical gap from the right. Given the previous rule, conceptually closing the gap, can not be seen as *conceptually* changing their values. This means the only *implementation* would be to shift the values in order.

**By means of explanation.**

The Standard is dealing with the abstract *concept* not the actual implementation, although its statements do impact the implementation.

*Conceptually* erasing an element simply removes it and nothing more. So given the sequence:

```
3  5  7  4  2  9 (6 values)
```

If we erase the 3rd element what does that *conceptually* give us?

```
3  5  4  2  9 (5 values)
```

This must be true because of the first statement above:

> **23.2.1**
>   **11** Unless otherwise specified (either explicitly or by defining a function in terms of other functions), invoking a container member function or passing a container as an argument to a library function shall not invalidate iterators to, or change the values of, objects within that container.

If the *implementation* reordered the elements, say by swapping the erased element with the end element that rule would be broken because we would end up with this:

```
3  5  9  4  2
```

Conceptually the resulting value to the right of the erased element has changed from a 4 to a 9, thus breaking the rule.

Comment: *If you can't "change the values of" then you can't arbitrarily re-order elements (like swapping the end value with the erased one).*
Why not? The value of the elements doesn't change, it is just the ordering that changes.
*This implies that the conceptual erasure of an element is implemented by closing the physical gap from the right.*
I don't think this guarantees anything regarding reordering. If you moved the element that was following `q` prior to the element being erased to, say, the beginning you could simply return `X.begin()` and that iterator would still satisfy the requirement.

Comment: This was satisfying until I read Corristo's comment, which raises very good points.

Comment: @Corristo Looking at it purely conceptually, erasing an element simply means removing that one value. The first statement means that after that value has gone none of the other values will have changed. So no re-ordering can take place. Obviously values do change in the implementation but the standard doesn't deal with the implementation, only the concept. That's how I see it The second statement, however, forces the implementation to shift left.

Comment: @Galik I think everyone here agrees that this is the intention of the standard, the problem is that there is no clear definition that says so. This relies on the interpretation of "strictly linear arrangement", which never is defined.

Comment: @Corristo To be honest I don't find the term "strictly linear arrangement" at all ambiguous. For me the key is realizing that the standard deals in *concepts* and leaves the implementation to the implementers.

Comment: @Galik The issue I have with the term is that apparently the Sequence concepts is intended to model mathematical sequences, where you also sometimes see the notation of `a[n]` for the `n-th` element of a sequence $\{a_i\}_{i=0,1,...}$. But there a "linear sequence" is something completely different. So "strictly linear" doesn't actually mean anything unless it is defined. The problem with `erase` is that this isn't something you can do with a sequence in mathematics either. The closest thing you could do is define a subsequence that doesn't include the "erased" element.

Comment: @Corristo I was viewing it as a collection concept. You can have a jumble of billiard balls in a bag. But if you want to deal with the balls in a strictly linear way (linear = line) you have to line them up - place them in a line. That implies arbitrary order and a given sequence. Your math is closer to the *implementation* rather than the pure concept. Erasing a ball simply means it disappears - nothing else changes.

Comment: @Galik: _"the standard deals in concepts and leaves the implementation to the implementers"_ Yet the entire purpose of the standard is to emplace constraints on implementors. We require it to be precise.